# I need to find the file path and file name of a file that matches the string lastline

Tags: c#, windows

My path is

> E:\Program Files (x86)\foobar2000\library\

And I need to find a file which has a filename containing the variable lastline.

Then i need to save that filepath + filename to a string.

I have tried...

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\Program Files (x86)\\foobar2000\\library\\", " *.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++) {
    if (filePaths[i].Contains(lastline)) {
        Console.WriteLine(filePaths[i]);
    }
}
```

all it does is return every file, not the one containing the string lastline

Comment: So what's the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Comment: im not getting an error its just not returning what i want. i want just the filepath of the file containing the string lastname.

Comment: If it displays every file path then every file path contains the value of `lastline`.  Presumably `lastline` has a value other than what you intended.  Either that or you should only be testing each file name rather than the entire path.

Comment: By the way, while a `for` loop in this situation is not wrong, a `foreach` loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: Are you sure you initialized the `lastline` variable? All strings contain the empty string. Regardless, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to tell you what's wrong with the code.

Comment: im trying to post my code... but im new to stack overflow and its saying its not formatting right.

Comment: @PeterDuniho im using visual studio and am new to stack overflow. Please tell me how to properly paste my code without it formatting incorrectly.

Comment: Formatting isn't really the issue here. It's a matter of taking the time to create a suitable code example. Usually, you can paste straight in from Visual Studio. Assuming you are pasting the entire .cs file contents, you can select the pasted-in code and press Control-K. Alternatively, arguably it is reasonable to omit `using` directives and `namespace` declarations, and just paste in the `class` declaration where all the code actually is. In that case, usually the code is already indented the 4 spaces Stack Overflow needs to format the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
try
        {
            string lastline = "Controller"; // assuming you know the file your searching for
            foreach (string filePaths in Directory.GetDirectories(@"E:\Program Files (x86)\foobar2000\library\"))
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(filePaths, "*" + lastline + "*.*"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(f); // would print the filepath n the file name

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the file name is text that i am getting from user input. so i do not yet know what the filename is. i just need to find the filename that contains the variable lastline inputed by the user. for example, if the user inputs cats, then it will look for a file with cats in it, and then it would display something like 13123cats.jpeg

Comment: This would work.. I just checked.. anyways good luck(y)...

Comment: doesnt work thanks for the input though

Comment: Any bugs or errors it's giving out? Why isn't it working?

Comment: its seaching for the exact filename, but i need to search for a string in the filename. Basically is what i am doing is, when someone enters a part of a name of a song like 'eye'. Then i need the program to look for all mp3 files with the string 'eye' in it then return the path with the filename like so. "E:\Program Files (x86)\foobar2000\library\survivor\eye of the tiger.mp3"

Comment: @toClean This works the way you intend it to work. Hope it works for u too.. next time be more specific like u were in the comment above. Thank you.

Comment: it says illegal characters in path. i think you almost got it figured out.

Comment: line number?  as in which line number u get the error? or in this case which place ur getting the error?

Comment: which wildcards? the asterisk in the  `"*" + lastline + "*.*"` ?

Comment: alright, sorry nvm what i said about the wild cards. I now have it working except for after it prints the correct file and filepath, it prints all the files and filepaths.

Comment: Thank you.. pls mark the answer answered if it works..

Comment: thanks so much for your help, sorry i did not explain very well.